# Question with answers, deleted by vote

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions, post-ban

My previous question had 2 answers. I tried to delete it because it was duplicate. An alert like box appeared saying "if you delete answered question continuously you might be banned from asking questions" so I did not delete it. Later it was deleted by votes. Will it have any effect on my privilege to ask questions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will it have any effect on my privilege to ask questions ?

Yes, it will.

Negative score on questions, having the questions closed and/or deleted - all of those have an effect towards question ban.

However, here on MSE the threshold is higher than on most other sites, due to the nature of the site that involves posting things that some people won't always agree with, and this very question of yours proves you are not banned yet.

Bottom line, just be careful and try not to post things that people are not going to agree with, and you're still pretty far away from a question ban as far as I can tell.